# Confused about FATAL EXCEPTION:main caused by NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, fatal-error

I am super confused right now! I am making my first android app and when I just had one activity, I had no errors. But after I added a second activity I get a FATAL EXCEPTION:main.

Here is my stacktrace:

```
09-13 11:08:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(14008): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-13 11:08:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(14008): Process: com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz, PID:        14008
09-13 11:08:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(14008): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz/com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.QuizActivity}:java.lang.NullPointerException
09-13 11:08:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(14008):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
09-13 11:08:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(14008):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
09-13 11:08:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(14008):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
09-13 11:08:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(14008):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
09-13 11:08:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(14008):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-13 11:08:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(14008):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
09-13 11:08:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(14008):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
09-13 11:08:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(14008):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-13 11:08:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(14008):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-13 11:08:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(14008):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
09-13 11:08:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(14008):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
09-13 11:08:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(14008):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-13 11:08:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(14008): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-13 11:08:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(14008):    at com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.QuizActivity.updateQuestion(QuizActivity.java:40)
09-13 11:08:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(14008):    at com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.QuizActivity.onCreate(QuizActivity.java:70)
09-13 11:08:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(14008):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
09-13 11:08:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(14008):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
09-13 11:08:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(14008):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
09-13 11:08:12.106: E/AndroidRuntime(14008):    ... 11 more
```

But then, I go to line 70 in my QuizActivity.java, comment out a section of code, run it and get this error:

```
Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

Then I uncomment the section of code at line 70, rerun it, hit the back space on my emulator and my program is there, running just fine! I literally changed nothing in my code, and when I ran my program at two separate times, I got two completely different results! I would love an explanation as to why this happens!

Here is the code I commented out at first at line 70:

```
mQuestionTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
updateQuestion();
```

Here is updateQuestion() at line 40:

```
private void updateQuestion() {
    int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getQuestion();
    mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I did clean, build, and reran the program when I was getting the FATAL EXCEPTION:main error and I still kept getting the message.

Comment: `Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front` is not an error - it's a warning ;) Do a clean, rebuild, and run the app again.

Comment: I think you really have 2 questions here, 1 is your confusion about the activity not started warning, the second is needing help on your null pointer exception.  I tried to answer 1 below, once you are past the confusion about the warning, I think you should enter a second question showing more code to ask about you NPE

Answer (score 0):

You will getting the warining:

```
Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

if you try to re-run your app from eclipse without making any changes.  For example if you right click on your project and select "run as android application", if the app on the device is out of date eclipse will re-build it and re-launch the launch activity.  If you don't make any changes to the app and then once again right click on your project and select "run as android application", you will get that warning,  because eclipse is not updating the app, or even re-starting it,  it is just bringing the currently running app to the foreground.

In addition if your app crashes it may get restarted, so that may add to your confusion, since you think the app crashed and is not running, but in fact it is running, and can still just be brought to the front as stated in the warning.

Answer (score -2):

the cause is a NullPointerException. check the value in your code (debug may can help you).